# Как отключить рекламу?

Tags: android, реклама

Как отключить рекламу в `android` приложении после клика пользователя, например, на сутки? Стандартный баннер, который вызывается в `Activity`:

```
AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest)
```

Что с ним сделать, чтобы отключить после нажатия?

Comment: Отформатируйте, пожалуйста, код в вопросе. Читать не удобно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сохрани в shared preferences или в бд  переменную,которая хранит время последнего нажатия ,при включении приложения загружай переменную и сравнивай с текущей датой ,в последующем вызывай adview

Comment: а какой создать обработчик, что при нажатии на adView.loadAd(adRequest) был клик?